# Finding ALL paths between 2 points on a square Matrix

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory

READ CAREFULLY BEFORE MARKING AS DUPLICATE!

I have a matrix:
0 0 0 x 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 x 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0

You CANNOT move diagonally in the matrix!

I want to find ALL possible paths between the two 'x's. The only condition is, that the path cannot cross itself (so no cycles). Apparently the DSF algorithm would not find every single path (to understand why, see this paper: http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Graph/Undirected/Depth-first_search).

So what algorithms should else be used?

Comment: Could you give the answer for the example matrix - the count of all paths?

Comment: Why? It's a self-made nonsense matrix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DFS without a visited set WILL find all paths in a graph.

You will have to maintain a special visited set variation that is relevant only for the current path, and not global. To do so, every time you "finish" exploring a vertex, you will have to remove it from the set.

pseudo code:

```
DFS(source,target,visited,path):
   if (source == target): //stop clause
       print path
       return
   for each son v of source:
      if v is in visited: //the vertex is already in the current path
           continue
      path.append(v)
      visited.add(v)
      DFS(v,target,visited,path)
      visited.remove(v)
      path.deleteLast()
```

Complexity of this solution is exponential, but it is expected since there are exponential number of simple paths between two nodes.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll implement it, and give you feedback asap.

Answer (score 0):

My specialty!

Haskell code:

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

paths (a,b) (a',b') m n = solve [(a',b')] where
  solve result@((y,x):_) = do
    next@(y',x') <- [(y,x + 1),(y,x - 1),(y + 1,x),(y - 1,x)]
    guard (y' >= 0 && y' < m && x' >= 0 && x' < n && notElem (y',x') result)
    if next == (a,b) then [(next:result)] else solve (next:result)
```

OUTPUT:

```
*Main> take 2 . paths (0,3) (3,1) 5 $ 5
[[(0,3),(0,2),(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,4),(2,3),(2,2),(2,1),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(3,4),(3,3),(3,2),(3,1)]
,[(0,3),(0,2),(0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,4),(2,3),(2,2),(2,1),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(3,4),(3,3),(3,2),(3,1)]]
(0.02 secs, 1595416 bytes)

*Main> length . paths (0,3) (3,1) 5 $ 5
4914
(1.28 secs, 100724732 bytes)

*Main Data.List Data.Ord> minimumBy (comparing length) . paths (0,3) (3,1) 5 $ 5
[(0,3),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(3,2),(3,1)]
(1.42 secs, 101955224 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in the same problem as OP. I have read about it and was difficult to find a proper solution. Many solutions have a graphs approach but not matrix. The comment of @amit and this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/) help me alot.

Here you can find a working solution:
https://repl.it/@gmunumel/StarryUniqueLicense

Answer (score 0):

Here is the C++ soluton using DFS,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>


using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> Node;


class Graph {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj;
    int rows; 
    int cols;
    std::vector<std::vector<Node>> paths;
    // A recursive function used by getAllThePaths()
    void dfs_all_paths(int sx, int sy, int dx, int dy, std::vector<std::vector<bool>>& visited,
                            std::vector<Node>& path, int& path_index);

    public:
        Graph(std::vector<std::vector<int>> ); // Constructor
        void getAllThePaths(int sx, int sy, int dx, int dy, std::vector<std::vector<Node>>& paths_selected);
};

Graph::Graph(std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj_map)
{
    adj = adj_map;
    rows = adj_map.size();
    cols = adj_map[0].size();
}

void Graph::getAllThePaths(int sx, int sy, int dx, int dy, std::vector<std::vector<Node>>& paths_selected)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> visited(rows, std::vector<bool>(cols, false));
    std::vector<Node> path(rows*cols);
    int path_index = 0;
    dfs_all_paths(sx, sy, dx, dy, visited, path, path_index);
    paths_selected = paths;
}

void Graph::dfs_all_paths(int sx, int sy, int dx, int dy, std::vector<std::vector<bool>>& visited,
                            std::vector<Node>& path, int& path_index)
{
    visited[sx][sy] = true;
    path[path_index] = Node(sx, sy);
    path_index++;
    if (sx == dx && sy == dy) {
        std::vector<Node> selected_path;
        selected_path.insert(selected_path.end(), path.begin(), path.begin()+path_index);
        paths.push_back(selected_path);
    }else {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> points = {{sx+1, sy}, {sx-1, sy}, {sx, sy+1}, {sx, sy-1}};
        for(auto point : points){
            if (point[0] < 0 || point[1] < 0 || point[0] > rows-1 || point[1] > cols-1 || adj[point[0]][point[1]] == 1 || visited[point[0]][point[1]] ){
                
            }else{
                dfs_all_paths(point[0], point[1], dx, dy, visited, path, path_index);
            }
        }     
    }
    path_index--;
    visited[sx][sy] = false;
}



int main()
{
    // Given array
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph = { { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 } };
    Graph g(graph);
    std::vector<std::vector<Node>> paths;
    g.getAllThePaths(0, 0, 3, 1 , paths);

    for (auto path : paths){
    for(auto point : path){
            cout << "(" << point.first << ", " << point.second << ")";
    }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```