# Issue with storing values to a list in a recursive function in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to write a Python function that stores all the paths between two points on a grid. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498066/finding-all-paths-between-2-points-on-a-square-matrix) is the original question and I am inspired by the answers and tried to create a similar version in Python.

I was able to successfully print out all the paths found by applying a recursive function, but the problem was that when I needed them to be stored in a list, I got an list of empty list. I have tried using global variables and local variables as the list for storage, and they gave the same results. Could anyone please comment on my code below and suggest on where I did incorrectly?

Many thanks!

```
import numpy as np

#initialize a matrix
grid = np.arange(0, 1225).reshape((35,35))
m = 10
n = 5
#starting point
s = (0, 0)
#target point
d = (n, m)
results = []

#a function to find the next step in the path
def next_step(x, y):
    step = []
    dx = [0, 1]
    dy = [1, 0]

    for i in range(2):
        next_x = x + dx[i]
        next_y = y + dy[i]
        if next_x >= 0 and next_x <= n and next_y >= 0 and next_y <= m:
            step.append((next_x, next_y))
    return step

def print_all_path(s, d, visited, path):
    global results
    visited[s[0]][s[1]] = True
    path.append(grid[s[0]][s[1]])

    if s == d:
        results.append(path)
        print(path)
    else:
        for step in next_step(s[0], s[1]):
            if visited[step[0],step[1]] == False:
                print_all_path(step, d, visited, path)
    path.pop()
    visited[s[0]][s[1]] = False

def print_path(s, d):
    visited = np.zeros((35,35), dtype = bool)
    path = []
    print_all_path(s, d, visited, path)

print_path(s, d)
```

Comment: What is expected output and how does it differ from current output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that when you append, you only append `path` I suspect you did something like this:

```
# global 
all_lists = []

# your functions
...
def print_all_path(s, d, visited, path):
    global results
    visited[s[0]][s[1]] = True
    path.append(grid[s[0]][s[1]])

    if s == d:
        results.append(path)
        print(path)
        all_lists.append(path)
...
```

However, path is still linked to the original `path` variable.

You can solve this by using:

```
all_lists.append(path + [])
```

This copies the list and removes the link

So the overall program is now

```
import numpy as np

#initialize a matrix
grid = np.arange(0, 1225).reshape((35,35))
m = 10
n = 5
#starting point
s = (0, 0)
#target point
d = (n, m)
results = []
all_paths = []

#a function to find the next step in the path
def next_step(x, y):
    step = []
    dx = [0, 1]
    dy = [1, 0]

    for i in range(2):
        next_x = x + dx[i]
        next_y = y + dy[i]
        if next_x >= 0 and next_x <= n and next_y >= 0 and next_y <= m:
            step.append((next_x, next_y))
    return step

def print_all_path(s, d, visited, path):
    global results
    visited[s[0]][s[1]] = True
    path.append(grid[s[0]][s[1]])

    if s == d:
        results.append(path)
        all_paths.append(path + [])
        #print(path)
    else:
        for step in next_step(s[0], s[1]):
            if visited[step[0],step[1]] == False:
                print_all_path(step, d, visited, path)
    path.pop()
    visited[s[0]][s[1]] = False

def print_path(s, d):
    visited = np.zeros((35,35), dtype = bool)
    path = []
    print_all_path(s, d, visited, path)


print_path(s, d)
print all_paths
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks so much for the answer! This works perfectly! I am relatively new to Python, and had a a bit of problem understanding why this is the case. This issue of the list being copied from the original link rather than the updated one - why this is the case? Is it related specifically to the application of a recursive function?

Comment: @Lithium What happens is that you append `path` to your list. Now, if you change `path`, the variable you added to your list also changes (try A = [0,0] B = A A.append(1) print B), you can read more about it here (http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list)

Comment: @Lithium btw, if your question is answered it is good practice to accept the answer, this indicates to others that no more help is needed.

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes perfect sense. Just accepted the answer.